# Subsection out of margin in LYX

Tags: lyx, margins, lyx-layouts

I have a title of a subsection which is out of the margin of my document as can be seen below figure.

[image]

Can someone help if i can use maybe some kind of `ert` whichi will be inline with my content?

Comment: I just made in LyX a new standard book with only  a section with "Multinomial and Binary Logistic Regression Model"  and  the title is break correctly, so "Model" pass to the next line, aligned with "Multinomial". You are doing something more, maybe using  a hard space (`~`) before "Model", but with the information supplied is only a guessing game  ... except for you.

Comment: What is an `ert`??

Comment: @Bernard you will not like it :) https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/ERT

Comment: @scottkosty:  ot aghost of a chance that I knew it! Thanks for the link. Perhaps I should learn to speak Acronym…

Comment: @Bernard actually I forget what it means as well. And each time I remember I actually don't like what it stands for.